# Automatically change the data a user enters

Tags: excel, vba

When a user inputs a value in a certain column then this value should automatically be picked up and added as a suffix.

For example, user inputs "3", convert this to "Incident " & Cell.Value.

I am having problems with the OnChange Sub routine and I'm thinking I'm taking the wrong path to automatically get this converted when the user changes cell selection.

Any Tips anyone may give me perhaps please?

Comment: You should update your question with the code you have so far.  Then we can Tip more easily...

Comment: Have you considered using formatting instead, so that a number appears as text (custom format `"Incident " 0`)? It is simpler and you can use the cell in a formula as a number.

Comment: Why not `="Incident " & A1` in B1? Using events for this task sounds to me like overkill and something you will regret down the line...

Comment: To be honest I simplified the above example as I required further functionality apart from simply adding a prefix "Incident" hence I needed to get this done through a macro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code in the Change event of your sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (IsNumeric(Target.Value)) Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Value = "Incident " & Target.Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

`IsNumeric` assures you won't end up with "Incident Incident 9" when a cell is focused.
`Application.EnableEvents = False` will prevent from recursively call the Change event.

Comment: +1 but you will probably need to add something like: `If Not Intersect(Columns(1), Target) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then`

Comment: Thanks for this, in addition to Francis P's solution and the addition of Reafidy which was required, I also kept track of the original target address as the above code was resulting in replacing the new cell in focus instead of the one before onChange event. so for the sake of completeness the below is my resulting code:

Comment: `'Change G Column to Display hyperlink instead If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub 'make a hyperlink out of number in column If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J11:J999")) Is Nothing Then If Target.Value <> "" Then Dim addr As String addr = Target.Address If (IsNumeric(Target.Value)) Then Application.EnableEvents = False Dim link As String link = Addlink(Target.Value) Range(addr).Formula = link Application.EnableEvents = True

Answer (score 0):

Does it really need to say 'Incident' in the cell or is it ok if it just displays that way?

If all you need is for it to display that way on screen, then you can add "Incident" to the cells' formatting.  Open the Format Cells dialog box. In the Number category, select Custom and in the Type field add `"Incident "` in front of the original format type.

If Type is `"Incident "General` then when the user types in 12345 it will display as `Incident 12345`. If the Type is `"Incident "#,##0` then 12345 will display as `Incident 12,345`.